# Как сделать коммит чтобы он попал на проверку в gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, git-push, git-merge

Я первый раз работаю в компании, мне дали репозиторий в gitlab с ветками **master** и **dev**

Я сделаю свою ветку от **dev**, допустим **feature**, сделаю там пару коммитов, и потом солью с помощью **git merge** свою ветку **feature** в ветку **dev**

Мне после этого нужно просто в ветке **dev** написать **git push** и это пойдет на проверку в гитлаб моему лиду? Просто, я боюсь как-то испортить ветку **dev** и не знаю что будет после **git push**.
Могу ли я сделать все что я сказал без последствий?

Возможно у вас будет какой-либо совет\рекоммендация по тому что я написал, спасибо

Comment: как вариант можно спросить у руководителя, не стесняйтесь спрашивать, лишний вопрос поможет не запороть не только свою работу но и чужую :)

Comment: merge request можно сделать из интерфейса гитлаба

Comment: А можно коммиты на проверку отправлять?
Например есть вот merge request - это судя по всему для веток, а есть что-то такое же но для коммитов?

Comment: что в gitlab-ci будет запущено, а что не будет, целиком и полностью зависит от настроек gitlab-ci для этого хранилища. уточняйте у администратора/руководителя.